# Connect to Redis from Android emulator running in Docker

Tags: android, docker, redis, android-emulator

I have a Redis server running on host machine (port 6379, no public IP). Also there is a docker container running on this host, and inside this docker container there is an Android emulator. How can I connect from application running inside Android emulator to a Redis server on host machine. 
I assume there should be a way to create a proper port forwarding.

Host machine could be either AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu, or MAC.

```
# Inside docker container
# ip route
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0 
10.0.0.0/24 via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0 
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.4 

# Inside android emulator
# ip route
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15 
10.0.2.2 dev eth0  scope link 
172.217.7.238 via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0
```

So I can connect from Docker container to it's host using docker.for.mac.host.internal (or host.docker.internal on newer version), and I can connect from Android emulator to it's host using 10.0.2.2. So the question is how can I connect to Redis directly from Android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

To connect your host Redis to Emulator running inside the container:

- Either use Docker Default Bridge IP in your emulator settings
- By pass the Docker container networking using `--network=host` while running the emulator container. This way the container will be attached to your host network where emulator can connect to Redis via `localhost`. (This approach is a bit unsecure)

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by "use Docker Default Bridge IP in your emulator settings"? Second option is not suitable, because in the end there could be multiple dockers inside single host.

Comment: When you install Docker Engine on your machine, a default bridge IP is also created. You can check that with `ip a` command with the name `docker0`. Create\Use a custom bridge network with your emulator container to be able to connect to Redis running on the host. Click [Here](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-35-connect-to-a-database-running-on-your-docker-host) to learn more.